# Weird problem with the style of divs in IE 9

Tags: html

I'm having a confusing problem, when I open my website in Internet explorer, most of the div style is messed up, like border radius and positioning, I looked here and put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` in. When I loaded that it would look much more messed up then before, but when I took out the meta tag, and uploaded the new file and refreshed the page, it looked fine, but if i was to close IE 9 and go back to my website, it looked how it did without the meta tag

Comment: Do you have an example?
Are you using `<!DOCTYPE html>` to trigger standards mode?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for now, just put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` instead of IE=9 and it should work fine.

Comment: nope, it is doing the exact same thing, except when I delete the meta tag and upload it again, it doesn't become perfect like when I do it with IE 9. To explain how the page looks messed up when I put in the meta tag. it seems all the divs are trying to go to the top left.